# Move the overlay element back and forth

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two elements (main and bottom) and the bottom is overlaid on another with transparency.

```html
<div class="middle" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3); position:absolute; width:250px; height:300px;">This is middle part</div>

<div class="bottom" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3); position:absolute; bottom:250px; width:150px; height:200px;" ">This is bottom part</div>
```

When the element middle is focused, I want the element bottom to go back with transparency and when the bottom is focused, then the element middle to go back and bottom to be forward. is there any way?

Comment: JQuery can do this in 3 lines. Google is your friend.

Comment: Or CSS only, manipulating elements  `z-index` for `:focus`

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add `tabindex="0"` to the `div`s in order to make them focusable
2. Set `z-index: 1;` in `<selector>:hover` rule

Like this:

```css
.middle {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 50px;
}
.middle:focus {
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bottom {
  background: red;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
}
.bottom:focus {
  outline: 1px solid lightblue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="middle">This is middle part</div>

<div tabindex="0" class="bottom">This is bottom part</div>
```

---

Note that `tabindex="0"` makes the `div`s not only respond to mouse click, but also to tab navigation with the keyboard, when `tabindex="0"` is used. They will only respond to mouse, but not to keyboard focus when you use `tabindex="-1"`

Now follows a second example which is the same as above with the slight difference of the `div`s having `tabindex="-1"` instead of `tabindex="0"`. Note that you cannot keyboard focus them (but you can unfocus them with the keyboard)

```css
.middle {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 50px;
}
.middle:focus {
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bottom {
  background: red;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
}
.bottom:focus {
  outline: 1px solid lightblue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1" class="middle">This is middle part</div>

<div tabindex="-1" class="bottom">This is bottom part</div>
```

Comment: @MrigankPawagi Please elaborate: what is not working? What have you tested? Which browsers did you test in?

Comment: I think `:focus` doesn't work on all elements (like `<div>`s)

Comment: you need to set a value to tabindex to make sure this work in all the browsers `tabindex=-1`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd rather use `tabindex="0"`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex  `tabindex="0"` means that the element should be focusable in sequential keyboard navigation, but its order is defined by the document's source order.

Comment: it depends if yes or no you want a keyboard interaction .. not sure if it's really needed in this case.

Comment: I will incorporate this in my answer